# How to switch the Header a little bit to the bottom, if the login header pops up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

the Question is on the top. Please help.

The codes are too big, please go ahead to this Links on pastebin:

1. Index.html: http://pastebin.com/SjsWF2zi
2. Index.js: http://pastebin.com/1yu92g9M
3. Index.css: http://pastebin.com/0VTuupsc
4. The whole Page in a Image: http://prntscr.com/9l8gy2

   5. another Picture, thats explains the fail: http://prntscr.com/9l8gm2

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, you should only include the code needed to prove your question. Not your entire code.